# How to calculate rows in query PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to 2 rows of query of **sum_hour(double type)** in database

1st row = sum_hour = **2.75**

2nd row = sum_hour = **3.00**

It belongs inside 2(two) groups which is **type_move = 'P'** and **(start date >= 2016-11-11 AND end_date <= 2016-11-15)** group. The code as below :

```
<?php
    $sql    = "SELECT  sum_hour,
                    SUM(sum_hour)
                    FROM table
                    WHERE type_move = 'P' AND user_id='username' AND (start_date >= '2016-11-11' AND end_date <= '2016-11-15')
                    GROUP BY sum_hour ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
            $hour = $row['sum_hour'];
            echo " Hours = " .$hour. "<br/>";
            print_r($row);
        }

        echo "Total hours = " .$hour. "<br/>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysqli_error($connect);
    }
?>
```

And the output as below :

**Hours = 2.75**

**Hours = 3.00**

**Total hours = ?**

My question is , **how to calculate 2 rows (Hours) above ?** I tried to run sql statement in phpmyadmin. It work and i can see the value sum up into = **5.75** but i don't know how to echo the total in browser

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your loop with this:

```
$totalHours = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        $hour = $row['sum_hour'];

        $totalHours += $hour;

        echo " Hours = " .$hour. "<br/>";
        print_r($row);
    }

echo "Total hours = " .$totalHours. "<br/>";
```

You need to store the first value in a variable then add the second one to the first value. Just make sure that the value can be read outside the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Just accept the answer when its ready to help others with the same question in the future. Good luck.