# How to read row of query and calculate multiple rows in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is extension of my previous question. 
My previous question solved my problem. the link [How to calculate rows in query PHP MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856868/how-to-calculate-rows-in-query-php-mysql)

But it only work if each row of query have different values (i.e **1st row = 1** and **2nd row = 1.5**). only then it calculate these two rows.

It does not work and it cannot calculate if the row have the same value (i.e **1st row = 1** and **2nd row = 1**). it only shows single row

The code as below

```
<?php
    $sql    = "SELECT  sum_hour,
                    SUM(sum_hour)
                    FROM table
                    WHERE type_move = 'P' AND user_id='username' AND (start_date >= '2016-11-11' AND end_date <= '2016-11-15')
                    GROUP BY sum_hour ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $total = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
            $hour   = $row['sum_hour'];
            $total += $hour;  
            echo " Hours = " .$hour. "<br/>";
            print_r($row);
        }

        echo "Total hours = " .$total. "<br/>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysqli_error($connect);
    }
?>
```

Can someone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems correct  in $total you should obtain 2

Comment: yeah . but it only work if the rows of query have different value .  if two rows have the same value, it does not work

Comment: check the typo : `total = 0;` will be `$total = 0;`

Comment: thanks . already changed . :)

Comment: is strange   .. try add  var_dump($total);  after   $total += $hour;   so you can check the result step by step

Comment: You're confusing the group by behavior for  sum_hour .. I posted an  answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the grouping in the SQL - it seems unnecessary. Grouping by a field and then doing the SUM of that field is a bit of a contradiction.

For example, if you have four rows like this:

```
| sum_hour |
------------
| 3.0      |
| 4.5      |
| 1.0      |
| 1.0      |
```

Then running your query as-is should produce the following rows:

```
----------------------------
| sum_hour | SUM(sum_hour) |
----------------------------
| 3.0      | 3.0           |
----------------------------
| 4.5      | 4.5           |
----------------------------
| 1.0      | 2.0           | <-- all the 1.0s in the table have been grouped together by the GROUP BY clause and then the SUM of those rows calculated
```

If you just want the total of all of them, this seems a bit pointless.

Change

```
SELECT  sum_hour, SUM(sum_hour)
FROM table
WHERE type_move = 'P' AND user_id='username' AND (start_date >= '2016-11-11' AND end_date <= '2016-11-15')
GROUP BY sum_hour
```

to

```
SELECT SUM(sum_hour) AS total
FROM table
WHERE type_move = 'P' 
  AND user_id='username' 
  AND (start_date >= '2016-11-11' AND end_date <= '2016-11-15')
```

This way you should just get one value returned from the query containing the SUM of all the matching rows in the database, and you probably don't need your PHP loop at all.

In my example above, this altered query would produce the following result:

```
---------
| total |
---------
| 9.5   |
```

Then in your PHP, you only need to retrieve one value, as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if($result)
{
    $total = 0;

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        $total = $row['total'];
    }

    echo "Total hours = " .$total. "<br/>";
//...etc
```

Comment: I see. i'll try it first . i'll let you know later  . thanks :)

Comment: Your suggestion code does not work . it didnt calculate the row  .

Comment: @Jamilah please give more detail. what was the result of the query using my suggestion? And what was wrong with it in comparison to yours? (I'm not talking about the PHP part yet, just the SQL)

Comment: when i run it in sql , the value sum perfect and no problem at all . but shoudl be (1 + 1 = 2) . but the ouput in php still show 1 . the output does not calculate the row .

Comment: @Jamilah so the query in my version returns one row, with the value 2 in it, correct?

Comment: @Jamilah I have edited the question to clarify what should be done in the PHP, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Jamilah: please try to avoid "does not work" as a response. It does not give any useful information to the person helping you regarding what might be wrong with their solution or your implementation of it. In general, be as detailed as you can when responding, so that less rounds of conversation are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful  with group by sum_hour

```
"SELECT  sum_hour,
           SUM(sum_hour)
            FROM table
WHERE type_move = 'P' AND user_id='username' 
AND (start_date >= '2016-11-11' AND end_date <= '2016-11-15')
   GROUP BY sum_hour ";
```

if  you have 2 rows with `sum_hour` = 1  then the  query above  return    `SUM(sum_hour)` = 2  because is the correct sum of a grouped  by key

try with 3 or more rows with sum_hour = 1 and you see that the sum increase 
for the fact that 1 became a key for group by